# Excluding captured group in re.split

Tags: python, regex

I have input similar to the following:

```
# file contents
US,This
is the title
CA, New Title
CA, Newer Title
```

I want to get the entry for each country. The final output should be:

```
# 3 items
['US, This is the title', 'CA, New Title', 'CA, Newer Title']
```

I am able to split on the ISO code, but I also need to include that. How would I modify the following regex to the correct one?

```
re.split(r'\n[A-Z]{2,3},', contents)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By using a lookahead.

```
>>> re.split(r'\n(?=[A-Z]{2,3},)', contents)
['US,This\nis the title', 'CA, New Title', 'CA, Newer Title']
```

Answer (score 4):

Through `re.split` along with `string.replace` function.

```
>>> s = """US,This
is the title
CA, New Title
CA, Newer Title"""
>>> [i.replace('\n', ' ') for i in re.split(r'\n(?=[A-Z]{2,3},)', s)]
['US,This is the title', 'CA, New Title', 'CA, Newer Title']
```

Through `re.findall` along with string.replace function.

```
>>> [i.replace('\n', ' ') for i in re.findall(r'(?s)(?:^|\n)([A-Z]{2,3},.*?)(?=\n[A-Z]{2,3},|$)', s)]
['US,This is the title', 'CA, New Title', 'CA, Newer Title']
```

To get the exact desired output, you need to use `re.sub` instead of `string.replace`.

```
>>> [re.sub(r'(?<=,)(?!\s)|\n', ' ', i) for i in re.findall(r'(?s)(?:^|\n)([A-Z]{2,3},.*?)(?=\n[A-Z]{2,3},|$)', s)]
['US, This is the title', 'CA, New Title', 'CA, Newer Title']
```

- `(?<=,)(?!\s)` matches all the boundaries which exists next to comma and it must not be followed by a space character
- `|` OR
- `\n` new line character.

Replacing the matched boundaries, newline characters with a single space character will give you the desired output.